# Get Data for today from sqlite using objective c

Tags: objective-c

How i can get today's data from sqlite database using objective c? I use this query but it returns all data from database:

```
const char *sql = "select * from SavedD where julianday('now')";
```

Please help me to retrieve today's data only.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];            
//Set the required date format 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString* cCurrentTimeStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:dDate]; 
NSString *cPrevTimeStamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:00 AM",cCurrentTimeStamp];
NSString *cNextTimeStamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 23:59 PM",cCurrentTimeStamp];
const char *sqlStatement="SELECT * from _tablename where iAgentId=? and dScheduleTIme BETWEEN ? and ?";
```

or if you are using any other formatter then append that type formatter time to prev  & next timestamp

Comment: Thank you svrushal, I solve my problem by using this query and display today's data                                                       const char *sql = "select * from SavedD where  DateADndTime = date('now')";

Comment: How I can display data for each day independently in Table View?         I use this query but it returns failed data                             const char *sql = "select * from SavedD where DateADndTime = ?";

Comment: Instead of ? can you use date('?')then append date in yyyy-MM-dd format to it.ex.date('2012-11-27')

Comment: I used this query to display date in Table View                   const char *sql = "select * from SavedD where (datetime('now','-7 day')) GROUP BY DateADndTime ORDER BY DateADndTime";
How I can show the related data for every date in the group?

Comment: How I can call every row in table view different method to display it in other table view? i use switch but its remain in case 0 for every row.

Comment: switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:{
                       
            DateEntity *DatEntit=[[self.datmod getDateAndTime] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text=DatEntit.TypeMeal;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = DatEntit.NumbCalories;

            }
            break;
        case 1:{
            DateEntity *DatEntit=[[self.datmod getDateData] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text=DatEntit.TypeMeal;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = DatEntit.NumbCalories;
        }
break;